# How to emulate Task.Wait() in WinRT?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, synchronous

I have read that if `Wait()` is called on a `Task` before it is actually started, then the `TaskScheduler` may attempt to start the task inline on the thread calling `Wait()`.  This is undesirable to me because I am trying to guarantee the order of execution of some operations, and the inline call may screw that up.  Basically, I am exposing two ways to queue items (One async and one sync).  The sync method was using `Wait()` to wait for the result of the operation once it entered the queue on another thread and was executed, but now I have switched it to this:

```
while(t.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
    Task.Delay(10).Wait();

t.wait();
```

This looks a bit scary, and smelly, but is there another way to wait for a task to finish without the scheduler attempting to schedule it inline?  Waiting like this seems to work, but I'd rather use an alternative method if there is one.  I'm restricted to the Windows Runtime Library.

Comment: Not an answer, but why are you waiting to begin with instead of using [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd270696.aspx) to be called back when the task is done?

Comment: You can always fall back to standard mechanisms like `ManualResetEvent` or is that not an option?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson This is on the sync side of my API.  The user will submit a task to the queue, and the thread will block until it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Pako suggested this in the comments, and it seems like a simple enough solution to combine with `ContinueWith`; this will synchronously wait until `MyTask` is done;

```cs
var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Task.Run(() => MyTask()).ContinueWith(x => { manualResetEvent.Set(); });

manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Simple!  I love it.  The only thing I changed is using the slim version of the reset event instead :).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to guarantee the order of some operations, then you use use the tool that's meant for that: `ContinueWith()`. If you `Wait()` on a `Task` that's returned from that method, you can be sure that the `Task` won't be started prematurely.

But using `Wait()` in combination with `async` methods can be quite dangerous and very often leads to deadlocks. If you have an asynchronous version of a method, there usually shouldn't be any reason for you to create a synchronous version too.

Comment: Valid advice.  I will try doing away with the sync versions and see if things still go well.